# Приложение продается на Google Play. Если начать продавать его через другие площадки как отреагирует на это Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Если начать продавать его через другие площадки (магазины, сайты) как отреагирует на это Google Play и можно ли делать такое вообще?

Как к такому относится Google (Play), есть ли какие-нибудь ограничения (санкции) со стороны Google (Play)?

С Google Play меня не выкинут если буду еще с кем-нибудь сотрудничать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких санкций со стороны Google не последует, ваш apk - это ваш apk, где хотите там и распространяете, главное не нарушать правила площадок (магазинов). Я одновременно продаю приложения на Amazon и Google Play (естественно убрав из амазоновской версии все ссылки на GP, потому что они там не нужны) и претензий по этому поводу не одна из сторон ко мне не предъявляла.